# Bunch of Violations due to iframe Embed Video from youtube?

Tags: javascript, html, css, console

I got several violation messages on my console.
How can I overcome them.

I think javasctipt is not working cause of them.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

That is not an error.

The text in your console is from **Google Update** terms and services.